# MD5 implementation in PHP - where am I going wrong?

Tags: php, md5

I know that this might be a long stretch, but could someone possibly tell me where my current implementation of the MD5 algorithm in PHP is going wrong? I just can't seem to work out what's wrong with it.

It returns a 32 character hex string (25% of the time it produces a string less than 32 characters though), but it isn't producing the same 32 chars that the built-in MD5 function does.

Thank you very much.

---

```
<?php

function MD($string){
$a = "67452301";
$b = "EFCDAB89";
$c = "98BADCFE";
$d = "10325476";

$words = init($string);

for($i = 0; $i <= count($words)/16-1; $i++){
    $A = $a;
    $B = $b;
    $C = $c;
    $D = $d;

    /* ROUND 1 */
    FF ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[0 + ($i * 16)], 7, "d76aa478"); 
    FF ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[1 + ($i * 16)], 12, "e8c7b756"); 
    FF ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[2 + ($i * 16)], 17, "242070db"); 
    FF ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[3 + ($i * 16)], 22, "c1bdceee"); 
    FF ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[4 + ($i * 16)], 7, "f57c0faf"); 
    FF ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[5 + ($i * 16)], 12, "4787c62a"); 
    FF ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[6 + ($i * 16)], 17, "a8304613"); 
    FF ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[7 + ($i * 16)], 22, "fd469501"); 
    FF ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[8 + ($i * 16)], 7, "698098d8"); 
    FF ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[9 + ($i * 16)], 12, "8b44f7af"); 
    FF ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[10 + ($i * 16)], 17, "ffff5bb1"); 
    FF ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[11 + ($i * 16)], 22, "895cd7be"); 
    FF ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[12 + ($i * 16)], 7, "6b901122"); 
    FF ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[13 + ($i * 16)], 12, "fd987193"); 
    FF ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[14 + ($i * 16)], 17, "a679438e"); 
    FF ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[15 + ($i * 16)], 22, "49b40821"); 

    /* ROUND 2 */
    GG ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[1 + ($i * 16)], 5, "f61e2562"); 
    GG ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[6 + ($i * 16)], 9, "c040b340"); 
    GG ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[11 + ($i * 16)], 14, "265e5a51"); 
    GG ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[0 + ($i * 16)], 20, "e9b6c7aa"); 
    GG ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[5 + ($i * 16)], 5, "d62f105d"); 
    GG ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[10 + ($i * 16)], 9, "02441453"); 
    GG ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[15 + ($i * 16)], 14, "d8a1e681"); 
    GG ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[4 + ($i * 16)], 20, "e7d3fbc8"); 
    GG ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[9 + ($i * 16)], 5, "21e1cde6"); 
    GG ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[14 + ($i * 16)], 9, "c33707d6"); 
    GG ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[3 + ($i * 16)], 14, "f4d50d87"); 
    GG ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[8 + ($i * 16)], 20, "455a14ed"); 
    GG ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[13 + ($i * 16)], 5, "a9e3e905"); 
    GG ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[2 + ($i * 16)], 9, "fcefa3f8"); 
    GG ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[7 + ($i * 16)], 14, "676f02d9"); 
    GG ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[12 + ($i * 16)], 20, "8d2a4c8a"); 

    /* ROUND 3 */
    HH ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[5 + ($i * 16)], 4, "fffa3942"); 
    HH ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[8 + ($i * 16)], 11, "8771f681"); 
    HH ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[11 + ($i * 16)], 16, "6d9d6122"); 
    HH ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[14 + ($i * 16)], 23, "fde5380c"); 
    HH ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[1 + ($i * 16)], 4, "a4beea44"); 
    HH ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[4 + ($i * 16)], 11, "4bdecfa9"); 
    HH ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[7 + ($i * 16)], 16, "f6bb4b60"); 
    HH ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[10 + ($i * 16)], 23, "bebfbc70"); 
    HH ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[13 + ($i * 16)], 4, "289b7ec6"); 
    HH ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[0 + ($i * 16)], 11, "eaa127fa"); 
    HH ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[3 + ($i * 16)], 16, "d4ef3085"); 
    HH ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[6 + ($i * 16)], 23, "04881d05"); 
    HH ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[9 + ($i * 16)], 4, "d9d4d039"); 
    HH ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[12 + ($i * 16)], 11, "e6db99e5"); 
    HH ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[15 + ($i * 16)], 16, "1fa27cf8"); 
    HH ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[2 + ($i * 16)], 23, "c4ac5665"); 

    /* ROUND 4 */
    II ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[0 + ($i * 16)], 6, "f4292244"); 
    II ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[7 + ($i * 16)], 10, "432aff97"); 
    II ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[14 + ($i * 16)], 15, "ab9423a7"); 
    II ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[5 + ($i * 16)], 21, "fc93a039"); 
    II ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[12 + ($i * 16)], 6, "655b59c3"); 
    II ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[3 + ($i * 16)], 10, "8f0ccc92"); 
    II ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[10 + ($i * 16)], 15, "ffeff47d"); 
    II ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[1 + ($i * 16)], 21, "85845dd1"); 
    II ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[8 + ($i * 16)], 6, "6fa87e4f"); 
    II ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[15 + ($i * 16)], 10, "fe2ce6e0"); 
    II ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[6 + ($i * 16)], 15, "a3014314"); 
    II ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[13 + ($i * 16)], 21, "4e0811a1"); 
    II ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[4 + ($i * 16)], 6, "f7537e82"); 
    II ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[11 + ($i * 16)], 10, "bd3af235"); 
    II ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[2 + ($i * 16)], 15, "2ad7d2bb"); 
    II ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[9 + ($i * 16)], 21, "eb86d391"); 

    addVars($a, $b, $c, $d, $A, $B, $C, $D);    
}
    $MD5 = $a.$b.$c.$d;
    return $MD5;
}

/* General functions */

function hexbin($str){
    $hexbinmap = array("0" => "0000"
                     , "1" => "0001"
                     , "2" => "0010"
                     , "3" => "0011"
                     , "4" => "0100"
                     , "5" => "0101"
                     , "6" => "0110"
                     , "7" => "0111"
                     , "8" => "1000"
                     , "9" => "1001"
                     , "A" => "1010"
                     , "a" => "1010"
                     , "B" => "1011"
                     , "b" => "1011"
                     , "C" => "1100"
                     , "c" => "1100"
                     , "D" => "1101"
                     , "d" => "1101"
                     , "E" => "1110"
                     , "e" => "1110"
                     , "F" => "1111"
                     , "f" => "1111");                    
    $bin = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
    {
        $bin .= $hexbinmap[$str[$i]];
    }
    $bin = ltrim($bin, '0'); 
    // echo "Original: ".$str."  New: ".$bin."<br />";
    return $bin;
}

function strhex($str){
    $hex = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
    {
        $hex = $hex.dechex(ord($str[$i]));
    }
    return $hex;
}


/* MD5-specific functions */

function init($string){
    $len = strlen($string);
    $hex = strhex($string); // convert ascii string to hex
    $bin = hexbin($hex); // convert hex string to bin
    $padded = pad($bin);
    $padded = pad($padded, 1, $len);
    $block = str_split($padded, 32);
    return $block;
}

function pad($bin, $type=0, $len = 0){
    if($type == 0){
        $bin = $bin."1";
        $buff = strlen($bin) % 512;
        if($buff != 448){
            while(strlen($bin) % 512 != 448){
                $bin = $bin."0";
            }
        }
    }
    // append length (b) of string to latter 64 bits
    elseif($type == 1){
        $bLen = decbin($len);
        if(strlen($bLen) > 64){
            $words = truncate64($bLen);
            $bin .= $words[1].$words[0];
        }
        else{
            while(strlen($bLen) < 64){
                $bLen .= "0";
            }
            $words = str_split ($bLen, 32);
            $bin .= $words[1].$words[0];
        }

    }
    return $bin;
}

function truncate64($string){
    $trunc = substr($string, strlen($string) - 64, 64);
    $trunc = str_split ($trunc, 32);
    return $trunc;
}


/* MD5 base functions */

function F($X, $Y, $Z){
    $X = hexbin($X);
    $Y = hexbin($Y);
    $Z = hexbin($Z);
    $calc = ($X & $Y) | ((~ $X) & $Z); // X AND Y OR NOT X AND Z
    $calc = bindec($calc);
    return  $calc; 
}

function G($X, $Y, $Z){
    $X = hexbin($X);
    $Y = hexbin($Y);
    $Z = hexbin($Z);
    $calc = ($X & $Z) | ($Y & (~ $Z)) ; // X AND Z OR Y AND NOT Z
    $calc = bindec($calc);
    return  $calc; 
}

function H($X, $Y, $Z){
    $X = hexbin($X);
    $Y = hexbin($Y);
    $Z = hexbin($Z);
    $calc = $X ^ $Y ^ $Z; // X XOR Y XOR Z
    $calc = bindec($calc);
    return  $calc; 
}

function I($X, $Y, $Z){
    $X = hexbin($X);
    $Y = hexbin($Y);
    $Z = hexbin($Z);
    $calc = $Y ^ ($X | (~ $Z)) ; // Y XOR (X OR NOT Z)
    $calc = bindec($calc);
    return  $calc; 
}

/* MD5 round functions */

/*
$A - hex, $B - hex, $C - hex, $D - hex (F - dec)
$M - binary
$s - decimal
$t - hex
*/
function FF(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t){
    $A = hexdec($A);
    $t = hexdec($t);
    $M = bindec($M);
    $A = hexdec($B) + (($A + F($B, $C, $D) + $M + $t)); //decimal
    $A = rotate($A, $s);
}

function GG(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t){
    $A = hexdec($A);
    $t = hexdec($t);
    $M = bindec($M);
    $A = hexdec($B) + (($A + G($B, $C, $D) + $M + $t)); //decimal
    $A = rotate($A, $s);
}

function HH(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t){
    $A = hexdec($A);
    $t = hexdec($t);
    $M = bindec($M);
    $A = hexdec($B) + (($A + H($B, $C, $D) + $M + $t)); //decimal
    $A = rotate($A, $s);
}

function II(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t){
    $A = hexdec($A);
    $t = hexdec($t);
    $M = bindec($M);
    $A = hexdec($B) + (($A + I($B, $C, $D) + $M + $t)); //decimal
    $A = rotate($A, $s);
}

// shift
function rotate($decimal, $bits) { //returns hex
  $binary = decbin($decimal);
  $shifted = substr($binary, $bits).substr($binary, 0, $bits);
  $hexshift = base_convert($shifted, 2, 16);
  return $hexshift;
}

function addVars(&$a, &$b, &$c, &$d, $A, $B, $C, $D){
    $A = hexdec($A);
    $B = hexdec($B);
    $C = hexdec($C);
    $D = hexdec($D);
    $aa = hexdec($a);
    $bb = hexdec($b);
    $cc = hexdec($c);
    $dd = hexdec($d);

    $aa = $aa + $A;
    $bb = $bb + $A;
    $cc = $cc + $A;
    $dd = $dd + $A;

    $a = dechex($aa);
    $b = dechex($bb);
    $c = dechex($cc);
    $d = dechex($dd);
}

?>
```

Comment: Moved code from pastebin over here (in the future, don't worry, there's a max size to code windows)

Comment: What you should do is `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. That will tell you about some obvious errors like misspelled variable names and probably some other things.

Comment: Another thing I'd like to note is that you can add a comma after the last element in an `array(...)` (but not in an argument list). That's stylistically a bit better than what you have now with the leading comma.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL)
doesnt seem to be reporting anything new, but thanks anyway.
And I'll change that array now.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For some reason this question didn't leave me alone, so I went through
your code and fixed the bugs until it worked:

Before you go through this, I have two pieces of advice:

1. Don't convert back and forth between int values and hex/bin
   representations; convert to int values before any processing is
   done; makes the code much more readable.
2. Use [`call_user_func()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and implement the GG -> G, II -> I functions only once.

Also, there is one subtle bug remaining; an input string made up exclusively of zero characters will not be encoded correctly; I'll leave fixing that as an exercise for the reader :-).

- In `init()`:

What is appended is the length of the unpadded message in number of
**bits**, not number of characters:

```
- $len = strlen($string)
+ $len = strlen($string) * 8;
  $hex = strhex($string); // convert ascii string to hex
```

also, you have to pad what you get from `hexbin` otherwise the
subsequent call to `str_split` will get the alignment wrong:

```
- $bin = hexbin($hex);
+ $bin = leftpad(hexbin($hex), $len); // convert hex string to bin
  $block = str_split($padded, 32);
```

also, the byte order is little endian:

```
+ foreach ($block as &$b) {
+     $b = implode('', array_reverse(str_split($b, 8)));
+ }
```

- In `strhex()`:

There are a lot of padding errors like this; `dechex(ord("\1"))` is `'1'` not `'01'`:

```
- $hex = $hex.dechex(ord($str[$i]));
+ $hex = $hex.leftpad(dechex(ord($str[$i])), 2);
```

- In `pad()`:

The **byte**-order is litte endian (you're splitting into 32-bit words) and `truncate64()` is completely off the map :-):

```
-   $bLen = decbin($len);
-  if(strlen($bLen) > 64){
-    $words = truncate64($bLen);
-    $bin .= $words[1].$words[0];
-  }
-  else{
-      while(strlen($bLen) < 64){
-        $bLen .= "0";
-      }
-    $words = str_split ($bLen, 32);
-    $bin .= $words[1].$words[0];
-  }
+ $bLen = leftpad(decbin($len), 64);
+ $bin .= implode('', array_reverse(str_split($bLen, 8)));
```

- In `F()`, `G()`, `H()`, `I()`:

Bitwise operators can't be used on binary strings:

```
- $X = hexbin($X);
- $Y = hexbin($Y);
- $Z = hexbin($Z);
- $calc = ...
- $calc = bindec($calc);
+ $X = hexdec($X);
+ $Y = hexdec($Y);
+ $Z = hexdec($Z);
+ $calc = ...
```

- In `FF()`, `GG()`, `HH()`, `II()`:

You are adding `$B` before rotation, it must be added afterwards; also, since you are going back and forth between string and int representations and `PHP_INT_SIZE` may be greater than 4 (e.g. on 64-bit platforms), you have to make sure you only use the lower 32-bits:

```
- $A = hexdec($B) + (($A + H($B, $C, $D) + $M + $t)); //decimal
+ $A = ($A + H($B, $C, $D) + $M + $t) & 0xffffffff; //decimal
+ $A = rotate($A, $s);
+ $A = dechex((hexdec($B) + hexdec($A)) & 0xffffffff);
```

- In `addVars()`:

`$A` is repeated for each addition, probably a copy-paste artifact :-):

```
- $aa = $aa + $A;
- $bb = $bb + $A;
- $cc = $cc + $A;
- $dd = $dd + $A;
+ $aa = ($aa + $A) & 0xffffffff;
+ $bb = ($bb + $B) & 0xffffffff;
+ $cc = ($cc + $C) & 0xffffffff;
+ $dd = ($dd + $D) & 0xffffffff;
```

- In `rotate()`:

There is a padding bug (again) in your rotate function. Just throw it away and replace it with:

```
+ function rotate ($decimal, $bits) { //returns hex
+     return dechex((($decimal << $bits) |  ($decimal >> (32 - $bits))) & 0xffffffff);
+ }
```

- In `MD()`:

Last but not least, you have to convert to little endian again:

```
- $MD5 = $a.$b.$c.$d;
+ $MD5 = '';
+ foreach (array($a, $b, $c, $d) as $x) {
+     $MD5 .= implode('', array_reverse(str_split(leftpad($x, 8), 2)));
+ }
```

The missing `leftpad()` function:

```
+ function leftpad($needs_padding, $alignment)
+ {
+   if (strlen($needs_padding) % $alignment) {
+       $pad_amount    = $alignment - strlen($needs_padding) % $alignment;
+       $left_pad      = implode('', array_fill(0, $pad_amount, '0'));
+       $needs_padding = $left_pad . $needs_padding;
+   }
+   return $needs_padding;
+ }
```

Full edited source:

```
<?php

function MD($string){
$a = "67452301";
$b = "EFCDAB89";
$c = "98BADCFE";
$d = "10325476";

$words = init($string);

for($i = 0; $i <= count($words)/16-1; $i++){
        $A = $a;
        $B = $b;
        $C = $c;
        $D = $d;


        /* ROUND 1 */
        FF ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[0 + ($i * 16)], 7, "d76aa478"); 
        FF ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[1 + ($i * 16)], 12, "e8c7b756"); 
        FF ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[2 + ($i * 16)], 17, "242070db"); 
        FF ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[3 + ($i * 16)], 22, "c1bdceee"); 
        FF ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[4 + ($i * 16)], 7, "f57c0faf"); 
        FF ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[5 + ($i * 16)], 12, "4787c62a"); 
        FF ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[6 + ($i * 16)], 17, "a8304613"); 
        FF ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[7 + ($i * 16)], 22, "fd469501"); 
        FF ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[8 + ($i * 16)], 7, "698098d8"); 
        FF ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[9 + ($i * 16)], 12, "8b44f7af"); 
        FF ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[10 + ($i * 16)], 17, "ffff5bb1"); 
        FF ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[11 + ($i * 16)], 22, "895cd7be"); 
        FF ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[12 + ($i * 16)], 7, "6b901122"); 
        FF ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[13 + ($i * 16)], 12, "fd987193"); 
        FF ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[14 + ($i * 16)], 17, "a679438e"); 
        FF ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[15 + ($i * 16)], 22, "49b40821"); 

        /* ROUND 2 */
        GG ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[1 + ($i * 16)], 5, "f61e2562"); 
        GG ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[6 + ($i * 16)], 9, "c040b340"); 
        GG ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[11 + ($i * 16)], 14, "265e5a51"); 
        GG ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[0 + ($i * 16)], 20, "e9b6c7aa"); 
        GG ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[5 + ($i * 16)], 5, "d62f105d"); 
        GG ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[10 + ($i * 16)], 9, "02441453"); 
        GG ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[15 + ($i * 16)], 14, "d8a1e681"); 
        GG ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[4 + ($i * 16)], 20, "e7d3fbc8"); 
        GG ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[9 + ($i * 16)], 5, "21e1cde6"); 
        GG ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[14 + ($i * 16)], 9, "c33707d6"); 
        GG ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[3 + ($i * 16)], 14, "f4d50d87"); 
        GG ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[8 + ($i * 16)], 20, "455a14ed"); 
        GG ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[13 + ($i * 16)], 5, "a9e3e905"); 
        GG ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[2 + ($i * 16)], 9, "fcefa3f8"); 
        GG ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[7 + ($i * 16)], 14, "676f02d9"); 
        GG ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[12 + ($i * 16)], 20, "8d2a4c8a"); 

        /* ROUND 3 */
        HH ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[5 + ($i * 16)], 4, "fffa3942"); 
        HH ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[8 + ($i * 16)], 11, "8771f681"); 
        HH ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[11 + ($i * 16)], 16, "6d9d6122"); 
        HH ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[14 + ($i * 16)], 23, "fde5380c"); 
        HH ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[1 + ($i * 16)], 4, "a4beea44"); 
        HH ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[4 + ($i * 16)], 11, "4bdecfa9"); 
        HH ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[7 + ($i * 16)], 16, "f6bb4b60"); 
        HH ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[10 + ($i * 16)], 23, "bebfbc70"); 
        HH ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[13 + ($i * 16)], 4, "289b7ec6"); 
        HH ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[0 + ($i * 16)], 11, "eaa127fa"); 
        HH ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[3 + ($i * 16)], 16, "d4ef3085"); 
        HH ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[6 + ($i * 16)], 23, "04881d05"); 
        HH ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[9 + ($i * 16)], 4, "d9d4d039"); 
        HH ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[12 + ($i * 16)], 11, "e6db99e5"); 
        HH ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[15 + ($i * 16)], 16, "1fa27cf8"); 
        HH ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[2 + ($i * 16)], 23, "c4ac5665"); 

        /* ROUND 4 */
        II ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[0 + ($i * 16)], 6, "f4292244"); 
        II ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[7 + ($i * 16)], 10, "432aff97"); 
        II ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[14 + ($i * 16)], 15, "ab9423a7"); 
        II ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[5 + ($i * 16)], 21, "fc93a039"); 
        II ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[12 + ($i * 16)], 6, "655b59c3"); 
        II ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[3 + ($i * 16)], 10, "8f0ccc92"); 
        II ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[10 + ($i * 16)], 15, "ffeff47d"); 
        II ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[1 + ($i * 16)], 21, "85845dd1"); 
        II ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[8 + ($i * 16)], 6, "6fa87e4f"); 
        II ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[15 + ($i * 16)], 10, "fe2ce6e0"); 
        II ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[6 + ($i * 16)], 15, "a3014314"); 
        II ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[13 + ($i * 16)], 21, "4e0811a1"); 
        II ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[4 + ($i * 16)], 6, "f7537e82"); 
        II ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[11 + ($i * 16)], 10, "bd3af235"); 
        II ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[2 + ($i * 16)], 15, "2ad7d2bb"); 
        II ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[9 + ($i * 16)], 21, "eb86d391"); 

        addVars($a, $b, $c, $d, $A, $B, $C, $D);        
}
  $MD5 = '';
  foreach (array($a, $b, $c, $d) as $x) {
      $MD5 .= implode('', array_reverse(str_split(leftpad($x, 8), 2)));
  }

        return $MD5;
}

/* General functions */

function hexbin($str){
        $hexbinmap = array("0" => "0000"
                                                , "1" => "0001"
                                                , "2" => "0010"
                                                , "3" => "0011"
                                                , "4" => "0100"
                                                , "5" => "0101"
                                                , "6" => "0110"
                                                , "7" => "0111"
                                                , "8" => "1000"
                                                , "9" => "1001"
                                                , "A" => "1010"
                                                , "a" => "1010"
                                                , "B" => "1011"
                                                , "b" => "1011"
                                                , "C" => "1100"
                                                , "c" => "1100"
                                                , "D" => "1101"
                                                , "d" => "1101"
                                                , "E" => "1110"
                                                , "e" => "1110"
                                                , "F" => "1111"
                                                , "f" => "1111");

        $bin = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
    {
        $bin .= $hexbinmap[$str[$i]];
    }
    $bin = ltrim($bin, '0'); 
        // echo "Original: ".$str."  New: ".$bin."<br />";
    return $bin;
}

function strhex($str){
    $hex = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
    {
        $hex = $hex.leftpad(dechex(ord($str[$i])), 2);
    }
    return $hex;
}


/* MD5-specific functions */

function init($string){
        $len = strlen($string) * 8;
        $hex = strhex($string); // convert ascii string to hex
        $bin = leftpad(hexbin($hex), $len); // convert hex string to bin
        $padded = pad($bin);
        $padded = pad($padded, 1, $len);
        $block = str_split($padded, 32);

        foreach ($block as &$b) {
            $b = implode('', array_reverse(str_split($b, 8)));
        }

        return $block;
}

function pad($bin, $type=0, $len = 0){
        if($type == 0){
        $bin = $bin."1";
        $buff = strlen($bin) % 512;
        if($buff != 448){
                while(strlen($bin) % 512 != 448){

                        $bin = $bin."0";
                }
        }
        }
        // append length (b) of string to latter 64 bits
        elseif($type == 1){
            $bLen = leftpad(decbin($len), 64);
            $bin .= implode('', array_reverse(str_split($bLen, 8)));
        }
        return $bin;
}

/* MD5 base functions */

function F($X, $Y, $Z){
        $X = hexdec($X);
        $Y = hexdec($Y);
        $Z = hexdec($Z);
        $calc = (($X & $Y) | ((~ $X) & $Z)); // X AND Y OR NOT X AND Z
        return  $calc; 
}

function G($X, $Y, $Z){
        $X = hexdec($X);
        $Y = hexdec($Y);
        $Z = hexdec($Z);
        $calc = (($X & $Z) | ($Y & (~ $Z))); // X AND Z OR Y AND NOT Z
        return  $calc; 
}

function H($X, $Y, $Z){
        $X = hexdec($X);
        $Y = hexdec($Y);
        $Z = hexdec($Z);
        $calc = ($X ^ $Y ^ $Z); // X XOR Y XOR Z
        return  $calc; 
}

function I($X, $Y, $Z){
        $X = hexdec($X);
        $Y = hexdec($Y);
        $Z = hexdec($Z);
        $calc = ($Y ^ ($X | (~ $Z))) ; // Y XOR (X OR NOT Z)
        return  $calc; 
}

/* MD5 round functions */

/*
$A - hex, $B - hex, $C - hex, $D - hex (F - dec)
$M - binary
$s - decimal
$t - hex
*/
function FF(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t){
        $A = hexdec($A);
        $t = hexdec($t);
        $M = bindec($M);
        $A = ($A + F($B, $C, $D) + $M + $t) & 0xffffffff; //decimal
        $A = rotate($A, $s);
        $A = dechex((hexdec($B) + hexdec($A)) & 0xffffffff);
}

function GG(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t){
        $A = hexdec($A);
        $t = hexdec($t);
        $M = bindec($M);
        $A = ($A + G($B, $C, $D) + $M + $t) & 0xffffffff; //decimal
        $A = rotate($A, $s);
        $A = dechex((hexdec($B) + hexdec($A)) & 0xffffffff);
}

function HH(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t){
        $A = hexdec($A);
        $t = hexdec($t);
        $M = bindec($M);
        $A = ($A + H($B, $C, $D) + $M + $t) & 0xffffffff; //decimal
        $A = rotate($A, $s);
        $A = dechex((hexdec($B) + hexdec($A)) & 0xffffffff);
}

function II(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t){
        $A = hexdec($A);
        $t = hexdec($t);
        $M = bindec($M);
        $A = ($A + I($B, $C, $D) + $M + $t) & 0xffffffff; //decimal
        $A = rotate($A, $s);
        $A = dechex((hexdec($B) + hexdec($A)) & 0xffffffff);
}

// shift
function rotate ($decimal, $bits) { //returns hex
    return dechex((($decimal << $bits) |  ($decimal >> (32 - $bits))) & 0xffffffff);
}

function addVars(&$a, &$b, &$c, &$d, $A, $B, $C, $D){
        $A = hexdec($A);
        $B = hexdec($B);
        $C = hexdec($C);
        $D = hexdec($D);
        $aa = hexdec($a);
        $bb = hexdec($b);
        $cc = hexdec($c);
        $dd = hexdec($d);

        $aa = ($aa + $A) & 0xffffffff;
        $bb = ($bb + $B) & 0xffffffff;
        $cc = ($cc + $C) & 0xffffffff;
        $dd = ($dd + $D) & 0xffffffff;

        $a = dechex($aa);
        $b = dechex($bb);
        $c = dechex($cc);
        $d = dechex($dd);
}

function leftpad($needs_padding, $alignment)
{
    if (strlen($needs_padding) % $alignment) {
      $pad_amount    = $alignment - strlen($needs_padding) % $alignment;
      $left_pad      = implode('', array_fill(0, $pad_amount, '0'));
      $needs_padding = $left_pad . $needs_padding;
  }
  return $needs_padding;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, this is an incredible answer. You've been a serious help.

Comment: @blake - No problem. I should have been using the time to get some work done, but answering questions is more fun :-)

Comment: @rocketeerbkw that's right, there is still a bug - I pointed that out in the answer.

Comment: @Inshallah I'm well versed in php but a complete algorithm (bit level manipulation) novice. Are you saying there is a bug other than the empty string one you mentioned?

Comment: @rocketeerbkw I didn't notice any bugs besides the one I mentioned. Also, I said something about a string made up exclusively of zero characters. I think I meant, a string made up exclusively of '0' characters. Can't really remember, was a long time ago :-). Did you run into any problems with the corrected algorithm?

Comment: @Inshallah without editing your code, MD('test') does not produce a valid hash. I have noticed that different hashes are produced depending on the version of PHP (broken in 4.4.9, different in 5.2 and 5.3). I'll have to come back to this when I understand more.

Comment: not work http://codepad.org/8fpmFgPX echo MD('hola').' == '.md5('hola'); e132a37fbcc583bae46a786359fdefda == 4d186321c1a7f0f354b297e8914ab240

Answer (score 6):

Good on you for trying! I've had a similar experience, one time long ago I implemented an MD5 algorithm in Tcl. The best way I found to debug it was to trace through it line by line, knowing what operation *should* be performed, and making sure by hand calculation whether the correct operation was indeed performed.

There's no easy answer to this, and it's impossible to tell what might be wrong from the code you posted without detailed analysis.

(I'm assuming that you already know about the standard [md5()](http://php.net/md5) function and you're doing this for learning purposes.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it suprising how much you overlook the "low-tech" ways of doing this type of thing when they're probably the best methods.

Comment: And yes, I know about the md5 function ;)

Answer (score 4):

If the code doesn't work for you use this code instead:

```
<?php

function MD($string){
    $a = "67452301";
    $b = "efcdab89";
    $c = "98badcfe";
    $d = "10325476";

    $A = $a ;
    $B = $b ;
    $C = $c ;
    $D = $d ;
    $words = ConvertToArray($string);    
    for($i = 0; $i <= count($words)/16-1; $i++){
            $a  = $A;
            $b  = $B;
            $c  = $C;
            $d  = $D;
     
            /* ROUND 1 */  
            FF ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[0 + ($i * 16)], 7, "d76aa478"); 
            FF ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[1 + ($i * 16)], 12, "e8c7b756"); 
            FF ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[2 + ($i * 16)], 17, "242070db"); 
            FF ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[3 + ($i * 16)], 22, "c1bdceee"); 
            FF ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[4 + ($i * 16)], 7, "f57c0faf");  
            FF ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[5 + ($i * 16)], 12, "4787c62a"); 
            FF ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[6 + ($i * 16)], 17, "a8304613"); 
            FF ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[7 + ($i * 16)], 22, "fd469501"); 
            FF ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[8 + ($i * 16)], 7, "698098d8"); 
            FF ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[9 + ($i * 16)], 12, "8b44f7af"); 
            FF ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[10 + ($i * 16)], 17, "ffff5bb1"); 
            FF ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[11 + ($i * 16)], 22, "895cd7be");  
            FF ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[12 + ($i * 16)], 7, "6b901122"); 
            FF ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[13 + ($i * 16)], 12, "fd987193"); 
            FF ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[14 + ($i * 16)], 17, "a679438e"); 
            FF ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[15 + ($i * 16)], 22, "49b40821"); 

            /* ROUND 2 */
            GG ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[1 + ($i * 16)], 5, "f61e2562"); 
            GG ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[6 + ($i * 16)], 9, "c040b340"); 
            GG ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[11 + ($i * 16)], 14, "265e5a51"); 
            GG ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[0 + ($i * 16)], 20, "e9b6c7aa"); 
            GG ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[5 + ($i * 16)], 5, "d62f105d"); 
            GG ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[10 + ($i * 16)], 9, "2441453"); 
            GG ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[15 + ($i * 16)], 14, "d8a1e681"); 
            GG ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[4 + ($i * 16)], 20, "e7d3fbc8"); 
            GG ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[9 + ($i * 16)], 5, "21e1cde6"); 
            GG ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[14 + ($i * 16)], 9, "c33707d6"); 
            GG ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[3 + ($i * 16)], 14, "f4d50d87"); 
            GG ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[8 + ($i * 16)], 20, "455a14ed"); 
            GG ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[13 + ($i * 16)], 5, "a9e3e905"); 
            GG ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[2 + ($i * 16)], 9, "fcefa3f8"); 
            GG ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[7 + ($i * 16)], 14, "676f02d9"); 
            GG ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[12 + ($i * 16)], 20, "8d2a4c8a"); 

            /* ROUND 3 */
            HH ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[5 + ($i * 16)], 4, "fffa3942"); 
            HH ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[8 + ($i * 16)], 11, "8771f681"); 
            HH ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[11 + ($i * 16)], 16, "6d9d6122"); 
            HH ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[14 + ($i * 16)], 23, "fde5380c"); 
            HH ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[1 + ($i * 16)], 4, "a4beea44"); 
            HH ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[4 + ($i * 16)], 11, "4bdecfa9"); 
            HH ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[7 + ($i * 16)], 16, "f6bb4b60"); 
            HH ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[10 + ($i * 16)], 23, "bebfbc70"); 
            HH ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[13 + ($i * 16)], 4, "289b7ec6"); 
            HH ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[0 + ($i * 16)], 11, "eaa127fa"); 
            HH ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[3 + ($i * 16)], 16, "d4ef3085"); 
            HH ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[6 + ($i * 16)], 23, "4881d05"); 
            HH ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[9 + ($i * 16)], 4, "d9d4d039"); 
            HH ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[12 + ($i * 16)], 11, "e6db99e5"); 
            HH ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[15 + ($i * 16)], 16, "1fa27cf8"); 
            HH ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[2 + ($i * 16)], 23, "c4ac5665"); 

            /* ROUND 4 */
            II ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[0 + ($i * 16)], 6, "f4292244"); 
            II ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[7 + ($i * 16)], 10, "432aff97"); 
            II ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[14 + ($i * 16)], 15, "ab9423a7"); 
            II ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[5 + ($i * 16)], 21, "fc93a039"); 
            II ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[12 + ($i * 16)], 6, "655b59c3"); 
            II ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[3 + ($i * 16)], 10, "8f0ccc92"); 
            II ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[10 + ($i * 16)], 15, "ffeff47d"); 
            II ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[1 + ($i * 16)], 21, "85845dd1"); 
            II ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[8 + ($i * 16)], 6, "6fa87e4f"); 
            II ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[15 + ($i * 16)], 10, "fe2ce6e0"); 
            II ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[6 + ($i * 16)], 15, "a3014314"); 
            II ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[13 + ($i * 16)], 21, "4e0811a1"); 
            II ($A, $B, $C, $D, $words[4 + ($i * 16)], 6, "f7537e82"); 
            II ($D, $A, $B, $C, $words[11 + ($i * 16)], 10, "bd3af235"); 
            II ($C, $D, $A, $B, $words[2 + ($i * 16)], 15, "2ad7d2bb"); 
            II ($B, $C, $D, $A, $words[9 + ($i * 16)], 21, "eb86d391"); 

            $A=AddUnsigned(hexdec2($A),hexdec2($a));
            $B=AddUnsigned(hexdec2($B),hexdec2($b));
            $C=AddUnsigned(hexdec2($C),hexdec2($c));
            $D=AddUnsigned(hexdec2($D),hexdec2($d));    
    }

   $MD5 = WordToHex($A).WordToHex($B).WordToHex($C).WordToHex($D);
   return $MD5;
}

function WordToHex($lValue) { 
    $WordToHexValue = "";
    for ($lCount = 0;$lCount<=3;$lCount++) { 
        $lByte = (hexdec2($lValue)>>($lCount*8)) & 255; 
        $C = dechex($lByte);
        $WordToHexValue .= (strlen($C)=='1')?"0".dechex($lByte):dechex($lByte); 
    }
    return $WordToHexValue;
}
   
function F($X, $Y, $Z){    
        $X = hexdec2($X); 
        $Y = hexdec2($Y);
        $Z = hexdec2($Z);
        $calc = (($X & $Y) | ((~ $X) & $Z)); // X AND Y OR NOT X AND Z
        return  $calc; 
}

function G($X, $Y, $Z){
        $X = hexdec2($X);
        $Y = hexdec2($Y);
        $Z = hexdec2($Z);
        $calc = (($X & $Z) | ($Y & (~ $Z))); // X AND Z OR Y AND NOT Z
        return  $calc; 
}

function H($X, $Y, $Z){
        $X = hexdec2($X);
        $Y = hexdec2($Y);
        $Z = hexdec2($Z);
        $calc = ($X ^ $Y ^ $Z); // X XOR Y XOR Z
        return  $calc; 
}

function I($X, $Y, $Z){
        $X = hexdec2($X);
        $Y = hexdec2($Y);
        $Z = hexdec2($Z);
        $calc = ($Y ^ ($X | (~ $Z))) ; // Y XOR (X OR NOT Z)
        return  $calc; 
}
 
function AddUnsigned($lX,$lY) { 
    $lX8 = ($lX & 0x80000000);
    $lY8 = ($lY & 0x80000000);
    $lX4 = ($lX & 0x40000000);
    $lY4 = ($lY & 0x40000000);
    $lResult = ($lX & 0x3FFFFFFF)+($lY & 0x3FFFFFFF);
    if ($lX4 & $lY4) {
        $res = ($lResult ^ 0x80000000 ^ $lX8 ^ $lY8);
        if($res < 0)
            return '-'.dechex(abs($res));
        else
            return dechex($res); 
    }
    if ($lX4 | $lY4) {
        if ($lResult & 0x40000000) {
            $res = ($lResult ^ 0xC0000000 ^ $lX8 ^ $lY8);
            if($res < 0)
                return '-'.dechex(abs($res));
            else
                return dechex($res); 
        } else {
            $res = ($lResult ^ 0x40000000 ^ $lX8 ^ $lY8);
            if($res < 0)
                return '-'.dechex(abs($res));
            else
                return dechex($res);
        }
    } else {
        $res = ($lResult ^ $lX8 ^ $lY8);
        if($res < 0)
            return '-'.dechex(abs($res));
        else
            return dechex($res);
    }
}
function hexdec2($hex , $debug = false)
{  
    if(substr($hex, 0,1) == "-")
    {
        return doubleval('-'.hexdec("0x". str_replace("-", "", $hex )));
    }
    return hexdec("0x".$hex);
}
 
function FF(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t){  
        $Level1 = hexdec2(AddUnsigned( F($B, $C, $D) , bindec($M) ));
        $level2 = hexdec2(AddUnsigned($Level1, hexdec2($t)));  
        $A = hexdec2(AddUnsigned(hexdec2($A),$level2));
        $A = rotate($A, $s); 
        $A =  AddUnsigned($A , hexdec2($B)) ; 
}

function GG(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t){
        $Level1 = hexdec2(AddUnsigned( G($B, $C, $D) , bindec($M) ));
        $level2 = hexdec2(AddUnsigned($Level1, hexdec2($t)));  
        $A = hexdec2(AddUnsigned(hexdec2($A),$level2));
        $A = rotate($A, $s); 
        $A =  AddUnsigned($A , hexdec2($B)) ;  
}

function HH(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t){
        $Level1 = hexdec2(AddUnsigned( H($B, $C, $D) , bindec($M) ));
        $level2 = hexdec2(AddUnsigned($Level1, hexdec2($t)));  
        $A = hexdec2(AddUnsigned(hexdec2($A),$level2));
        $A = rotate($A, $s); 
        $A =  AddUnsigned($A , hexdec2($B)) ;  
}

function II(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t){
        $Level1 = hexdec2(AddUnsigned( I($B, $C, $D) , bindec($M) ));
        $level2 = hexdec2(AddUnsigned($Level1, hexdec2($t)));  
        $A = hexdec2(AddUnsigned(hexdec2($A),$level2));
        $A = rotate($A, $s); 
        $A =  AddUnsigned($A , hexdec2($B)) ;  
}
 
function rotate ($decimal, $bits , $debug = false) { 
    return  (($decimal << $bits) |  shiftright($decimal, (32 - $bits))  & 0xffffffff);
}
function shiftright($decimal , $right)
{ 
    if($decimal < 0)
    {
        $res = decbin($decimal >> $right);
        for ($i=0; $i < $right; $i++) { 
            $res[$i] = "";
        }
        return bindec($res) ;
    } else 
    {
        return ($decimal >> $right);
    }
}
 
function ConvertToArray($string) {
    $lWordCount;
    $lMessageLength = strlen($string);
    $lNumberOfWords_temp1=$lMessageLength + 8;
    $lNumberOfWords_temp2=($lNumberOfWords_temp1-($lNumberOfWords_temp1 % 64))/64;
    $lNumberOfWords = ($lNumberOfWords_temp2+1)*16; 
    $lWordArray=Array("");
    $lBytePosition = 0;
    $lByteCount = 0;
    while ( $lByteCount < $lMessageLength ) {
        $lWordCount = ($lByteCount-($lByteCount % 4))/4;
        $lBytePosition = ($lByteCount % 4)*8;
        if(!isset($lWordArray[$lWordCount]))
            $lWordArray[$lWordCount] = 0;
        $lWordArray[$lWordCount] = ($lWordArray[$lWordCount] | (ord($string[$lByteCount])<<$lBytePosition));
        $lByteCount++;
    }
    $lWordCount = ($lByteCount-($lByteCount % 4))/4;
    $lBytePosition = ($lByteCount % 4)*8;
    if(!isset($lWordArray[$lWordCount]))
        $lWordArray[$lWordCount] = 0;
    $lWordArray[$lWordCount] = $lWordArray[$lWordCount] | (0x80<<$lBytePosition);
    $lWordArray[$lNumberOfWords-2] = $lMessageLength<<3;
    $lWordArray[$lNumberOfWords-1] = $lMessageLength>>29; 
    for ($i=0; $i < $lNumberOfWords; $i++) { 
        if(isset($lWordArray[$i]))
            $lWordArray[$i] = decbin($lWordArray[$i]);
        else
            $lWordArray[$i] = '0';
    }  
    return $lWordArray;
}; 
$str='string';
echo md5($str);
echo'<br>';
echo MD($str);
```

Comment: This one works for me - the accepted answer produces a different value to the built in md5 function - cheers Mb

Answer (score 0):

here my version, simplifying the main iteration

```
function MD($string)
    {
    $A = $a = "67452301";
    $B = $b = "efcdab89";
    $C = $c = "98badcfe";
    $D = $d = "10325476";

    $words = str2blks_MD5($string);   

    $torot=array("A","B","C","D");    
    $it=array(7,12,17,22,5,9,14,20,4,11,16,23,6,10,15,21);
    $funcs=array("F","G","H","I");    

    $moduls=array(0,1,1,5,5,3,0,7);

    $acs=array(     "d76aa478","e8c7b756","242070db","c1bdceee",
                    "f57c0faf","4787c62a","a8304613","fd469501",
                    "698098d8","8b44f7af","ffff5bb1","895cd7be",
                    "6b901122","fd987193","a679438e","49b40821",

                    "f61e2562","c040b340","265e5a51","e9b6c7aa",
                    "d62f105d","2441453","d8a1e681","e7d3fbc8",
                    "21e1cde6","c33707d6","f4d50d87","455a14ed",
                    "a9e3e905","fcefa3f8","676f02d9","8d2a4c8a",

                    "fffa3942","8771f681","6d9d6122","fde5380c",
                    "a4beea44","4bdecfa9","f6bb4b60","bebfbc70",
                    "289b7ec6","eaa127fa","d4ef3085","4881d05",
                    "d9d4d039","e6db99e5","1fa27cf8","c4ac5665",  

                    "f4292244","432aff97","ab9423a7","fc93a039",
                    "655b59c3","8f0ccc92","ffeff47d","85845dd1",
                    "6fa87e4f","fe2ce6e0","a3014314","4e0811a1",
                    "f7537e82","bd3af235","2ad7d2bb","eb86d391"); 

    for($i = 0; $i < count($words)/16; $i++)
        {
            $a  = $A;
            $b  = $B;
            $c  = $C;
            $d  = $D;
            $n  = 0; 

        for ($rot3=0;$rot3<4;$rot3++)
            {
            $minit=$moduls[$rot3*2];
        $madd=$moduls[$rot3*2+1];   

            for ($rot2=0;$rot2<4;$rot2++)
                {
                for ($rot=0;$rot<4;$rot++)
                {
                $word=$words[$minit + ($i * 16)];
                $nit=$it[$rot+4*$rot3];

                FGHI (${"$torot[0]"}, ${"$torot[1]"}, ${"$torot[2]"}, ${"$torot[3]"}, $word, $nit, $acs[$n],$funcs[$rot3]); 

                    array_unshift($torot,$torot[3]);
                    array_pop($torot);

                $minit=($minit+$madd)%16;
                ++$n;
                }       
                 }
            }

            $A=AddUnsigned(hexdec2($A),hexdec2($a));
            $B=AddUnsigned(hexdec2($B),hexdec2($b));
            $C=AddUnsigned(hexdec2($C),hexdec2($c));
            $D=AddUnsigned(hexdec2($D),hexdec2($d));    
            }
    return WordToHex($A).WordToHex($B).WordToHex($C).WordToHex($D);
    }
function WordToHex($lValue) 
   { 
    $WordToHexValue = "";
    for ($lCount = 0;$lCount<4;$lCount++) 
        { 
        $lByte = hexdec2($lValue)>>($lCount*8) & 255; 
        $WordToHexValue.= sprintf("%02x",$lByte);
        }
    return $WordToHexValue;
    }
function FGHI(&$A, $B, $C, $D, $M, $s, $t, $func)
        {
        $Level1 = hexdec2(AddUnsigned(FGHI2($B, $C, $D, $func) , bindec($M) ));
        $level2 = hexdec2(AddUnsigned($Level1, hexdec2($t)));  
        $A = hexdec2(AddUnsigned(hexdec2($A),$level2));
        $A = rotate($A, $s); 
        $A = AddUnsigned($A , hexdec2($B)) ; 
        }
function FGHI2($X, $Y, $Z,$func)
        {    
        $X = hexdec2($X); 
        $Y = hexdec2($Y);
        $Z = hexdec2($Z);

    switch ($func)
        {
        case "F":
                $calc = (($X & $Y) | ((~ $X) & $Z));break;
        case "G":
            $calc = (($X & $Z) | ($Y & (~ $Z)));break;
        case "H":
            $calc = ($X ^ $Y ^ $Z);break;
        case "I":
            $calc = ($Y ^ ($X | (~ $Z)));
        }
        return  $calc; 
    }
function dectohex($res)
    {
        if($res < 0)
            return '-'.dechex(abs($res));
        return dechex($res);    
    }

function hexdec2($hex)
    {  
    if($hex[0] == "-")   
        return doubleval('-'.hexdec(str_replace("-", "", $hex )));

    return hexdec($hex);
    }

function AddUnsigned($lX,$lY) 
   { 
    $lX8 = ($lX & 0x80000000);
    $lY8 = ($lY & 0x80000000);
    $lX4 = ($lX & 0x40000000);
    $lY4 = ($lY & 0x40000000);

    $lResult = ($lX & 0x3FFFFFFF)+($lY & 0x3FFFFFFF);

    $res=$lResult ^ $lX8 ^ $lY8;

    if ($lX4 & $lY4)                       return dectohex($res ^ 0x80000000);   
    if ($lX4 | $lY4) 
    {
        if ($lResult & 0x40000000)         return dectohex($res ^ 0xC0000000);
        else                               return dectohex($res ^ 0x40000000);       
        }                                  return dectohex($res);
    }
function rotate ($decimal, $bits) 
    { 
    return  (($decimal << $bits) |  shiftright($decimal, (32 - $bits))  & 0xffffffff);
    }
function shiftright($decimal , $right)
    { 
    $shift=$decimal >> $right;

    if($decimal >= 0) return $shift;
    return bindec(substr(decbin($shift),$right));
    }

function str2blks_MD5($str)
  {
  $nblk = ((strlen($str) + 8) >> 6) + 1;

  $blks = array($nblk * 16);

  for($i = 0; $i < $nblk * 16; $i++) 
                $blks[$i] = 0;

  for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
            $blks[$i >> 2] |= ord($str[$i]) << (($i % 4) * 8);

  $blks[$i >> 2] |= 0x80 << (($i % 4) * 8);

  $blks[$nblk * 16 - 2] = strlen($str) * 8;

  for ($i=0; $i < $nblk * 16; $i++)             
        $blks[$i] = decbin($blks[$i]);

  return $blks;
  }
$str='test';
echo md5($str); // 098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
echo'<br>';
echo MD($str); //  098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```